# how to delete entire line in sublime in windows

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

I have to use window based computer, i usually could delete a whole line using cmd + backspace in mac. Is it possible to do the same in windows without doing:

shift+home and then backspace.

Comment: Add the pointer to the beginning then use shift + end then press delete

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`CTRL + SHIFT + K` will delete a line in Sublime Text 3 on Windows.

Answer (score 29):

By default it is
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
which to me doesn't feel very comfortable.

If you want to use a custom shortcut instead:

1. Go to *Preferences* › *Key Bindings*,
2. On the right side (the user defined keymap), add this line:

   `{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro"} }`
3. Save.

Now you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as the delete line command!

Comment: and for anyone trying to do this on mac its { "keys": ["super+d"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro"}  }

Comment: Ctrl + D is one of the most useful feature to select next occurring of selected text. why would anyone want to replace that useful functionality with deleting line when all you need to do is get used to CTRL+SHIFT+K?

Comment: @TahaKhan Hmmm, the command you describe has me reaching for CTRL-F3. I have never used CTRL-D for this, whereas I have used that for line deletion.

Answer (score 5):

`Command + X` will work for Mac computers.

EDIT: but it will also "cut" the line. So you may lose your clipboard content.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> will delete a line in Sublime Text 3 on Linux(tested on Ubuntu 14.0), too.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> will delete a line in Sublime Text 3 on Mac OS, too.

Answer (score 2):

`CTRL + X` will do the job for you.

Comment: Yes, but that cuts the line so you lose your clipboard's contents.

Answer (score 1):

- Ctrl + X = Cut Line
- Ctrl + Shift + K = Delete Line